# Rails including .js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am curious about the way Rails includes .js files.
Asside from the asset pipeline, I'm curious about the .js files stored in the `view`.
For example, if you want to apply ajax call to an action called `like` in `PostsController`, you simply put the relevant ajax code in `like.js.erb` in the posts view folder. Then, the javascript is triggered automatically when the user calls the action `like`.

My questions are

1. Is it right that javascript files whose names match certain actions are called automatically when the action is invoked?
2. If I want to include a javascript file, which does not correspond to any action, in a certain view, what do I do? Just include it in the application manifest?
   More specifically, I have `tag-autocomplete.js.erb` in `views/post` right now. Do I move it to the `assets` folder and include it from the `application.css`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, though I don't see immediately what will happen if you have both like.js.erb and like.html.erb.  It seems like one or the other will be chosen, and it might be arbitrary.
2. I would normally inline the javascript in that situation, in a script tag.  If it truly will only ever be used in that view, that's reasonable.  On the other hand, the application.js is cached and that saves bandwidth to put whatever you can in there.  Since you're asking about things involving templating, though, I imagine caching isn't desirable.  To that, I say you should try to minimize your use of templating in JS.  Sometimes it makes sense, but be careful.

(FYI: [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb#L116) is where the core of the relevant functionality is defined.)

Comment: It's not arbitrary though, right?  The controller will have a respond_to block for the action that specifies the view is a js file.  If both views are present the one that is specified in the controller's action will trigger unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: The Accept request header is used by Rails to determine which formats are acceptable and used to invoke the first matching responder. So the order in which you define format.js, format.html, etc. in a respond_to block can affect which one Rails chooses.

Comment: I was only concerned with implicit rendering, as explicit rendering does not seem relevant to the question.  For implicit rendering, as far as I know it is still somehow arbitrary, but this makes much sense for explicit rendering.